# Binary Display with LEDs

Tags: avr, atmega, serial

I tried an example of code to display serial output on an array of LEDs.

```
#define F_CPU 1000000UL
#define BAUD 9600UL

#include <avr/io.h>
#include <util/delay.h>
#include <USART.h>
#include <pinDefines.h>


int main(void) {
    char serialCharacter;
    LED_DDR = 0xff;
    initUSART();
    printString("Connection Successful\r\n");

    while (1) {
        serialCharacter = receiveByte();
        transmitByte(serialCharacter);
        PORTB = serialCharacter;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The code for the serial connection:

```
#ifndef BAUD
#define BAUD  9600
#endif

#define   USART_HAS_DATA   bit_is_set(UCSR0A, RXC0)
#define   USART_READY      bit_is_set(UCSR0A, UDRE0)

#include <avr/io.h>
#include <util/setbaud.h>

void initUSART(void) {

    #define BAUDRATE ((F_CPU) / (BAUD * 8UL)-1) // Set Baud Rate Value for UBRR

    // Set register
    UBRR0H = (BAUDRATE >> 8);
    UBRR0L = BAUDRATE;
    UCSR0A |= (1 << U2X0);  
    // Enable USART transmitter and receiver
    UCSR0B = (1 << TXEN0) | (1 << RXEN0);
    // Set 8 data bits and 1 stop bit
    UCSR0C = (1 << UCSZ01) | (1 << UCSZ00);
}

void transmitByte(uint8_t data) {
    // Wait for empty transmit buffer
    loop_until_bit_is_set(UCSR0A, UDRE0);
    UDR0 = data;
}

uint8_t receiveByte(void) {
    // Wait for incoming data
    loop_until_bit_is_set(UCSR0A, RXC0);
    return UDR0;
}

void printString(const char myString[]) {
    uint8_t i = 0;
    while (myString[i]) {
        transmitByte(myString[i]);
        i++;
    }
}
```

The connection works well and the data I key in will be displayed on a serial terminal as expected. Though the display on the LED array is odd. No matter what I key in, I get the output on LEDS of 00001010 (8 LEDs each representing one bit) on PORTB of the ATMEGA328p.

[image]
[image]

Always the same 2 LEDs light up. When I press a key to be transmitted I get a short flicker of the LEDs and then going back to lighting up Bit 2 and 4. How can I fix this?

Comment: Can you set all the LEDs individually if you hard code the PORTB value with a minimal example?

Comment: yep! works perfectly well. If I input `PORTB = 0b00011100` I get the right LEDs lighting up

Comment: So... it must be something with the output of the serial connection?

Comment: When I printString(serialCharacter) I get this on my screen `¿`for the letter A. No matter what key I press, LEDs 0-6 flicker on the press of the Enter key and then LED 1 and 3 are constantly lighting up. Happens with every key.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Could your PC terminal program be set up to automatically send an ASCII line feed after every character. That would explain why the final character your MCU receives is 0Ah. Check that the terminal program is set to a simple mode.

Comment: Ha!! yyes!! solved it... I deactivated LF and CR and now its running smoothley! Thanks mate!

Comment: @sesc360, you're very welcome, have fun with it :-)